# Failed to set power on: org.bluez.Error.Blocked problem

Tags: archlinux

Recently I tried to use bluetooth on arch linux. I'm using WM so after installing packages such as:`bluez` and `bluez-utils` I ran a command `bluetoothctl`. Then I tried to run `power on` but I got an error `Failed to set power on: org.bluez.Error.Blocked`. I searched on the internet but I only found `Failed to set power on: org.bluez.Error.Failed` solutions, so it's not what I want.

Answer (score 45):

try:

```
rfkill block bluetooth
rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

and then open bluetoothctl again.
If it does't work I would try:

```
systemctl stop bluetooth.service
systemctl start bluetooth.service
```

Comment: Bluetooth has been an issue on Ubuntu for 20 years. The only way to manage Bluetooth in a reliable way there is with custom scripts, an intense wish to make it working and a but-load of patience. (OK. Not a very useful comment, but it was good for me.)

Answer (score 13):

In my case the driver was stuck somewhere (Linux 5.16.10 x86_64), the solution was:

```
# rmmod btusb
# modprobe btusb
# systemctl restart bluetooth
```

Comment: no luck even with this... still a worthy suggestion

Comment: Thanks !The `rfkill` solution stopped working on my machine for some reason. With yours, I even heard my headphones connecting and then disconnecting when restarting the service so in theory the last line isn't even necessary !

Comment: Thank you! Only this solution works on my Ubuntu 22 on 6.5 kernel